# how to create new zod schema with infering its type

Tags: typescript, types, interface, schema, zod

I want to reasign value of my object

i have interface like this

```js
interface Root {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
```

and i know how to create zod schema from that interface

```js
const zRoot: z.ZodType<Root> = z.object({
    userId: z.number(),
    id: z.number(),
    title: z.string(),
    completed: z.boolean(),
});
```

but, how to make schema that type like this?

```js
type RootObjectArray = {
    [F in keyof Root]: Root[F][];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This example provides an implementation of a validating schema for the `RootObjectArray` you provided and I think some proof it matches (hover over RootMatches and RootObjectArrayMatches). I've only tested it [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=53&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLwDRwFoQCYHkBGAVgKYDGM6W2AglFAIYCelOASvQO4DKAFvWMTgBfOADMoEEHABEyHNIDcAKCXEAHpFhiArgDtywCLrgBneqOIBpYoxMAeADIQIAa21g46mMV3YTiOABtFzhgYxMYKDCAcwBdAC44PRddCA5jIQA%20AAolODgAG2c3MESnV3clAEpEPLgoYhhtKGMCEnIAOhcbE2yiirAa%20n9s7sYIUThykqrA2OUhFXVNeFE9AyM4EH4AMQkQOwBZfk81b19-CCIyGBy6sZNEhvpsIwLGOFGbCbhjwbnUHVtmAdrpEnZrB8vD4-HAxj8-jkxolITUALyZX78QKQ2LVWr5BpNFpwNo3DriSQAUV0kWAxF6Dw6wOyX0Y6MxwRs6GBoLZVViVSG-gQdXyONCxnhkz%20CSxYBx8zqQgWKjC3igonopEErGc8FF%20W0JmIUAAkthErptCB8KblPlgJa4Nbbfa6jBgDACsREhEorpog64KRJGAfd5nfhnD76LpVUoYIwBHA9RAYGTyLQGB80QSgjtJXDvpM0zA5WXAjtYnMFsolKHdBEUGW4HnkB0ru0YNlDUkTebnR3XXaoNkqoDHUOOiPTePJ3BPd7fSgOv6YvO6qHwBHiNPoxBY7pN0IqvW1vpPZsYBBs0wuKQeMRtnZePxBNCLpg2Jw3wIciYj7PvQiRUJmMCvnw-41H2jbNiYUErn%20gh5oBT7bGuiHBkSzTGLy%20x2EgEphMW4yTMhcpUHejCQe%20iqYlkuT5PkZgWJCvQIe%20E5ip8Ywcqu9B0Ew2ScQIXKMIKdRnkoiwNkYzbIGW4HUW2q5djc2Q3tRD7ofQ2SKfqQr1kmKZUK27YdGEFhQHYJnED8Bnppkyh2d%202BKdcWZCbmq5WaatnJvZkyORmnkwNRmQqK5VIAI7aMAABu9A%20rSdgABroAAmpieZpac5ywplcAAPyfEVn6wnlpWRNogiJFqBQmjU9XJSaxmBam%20rHDAQH%20HmsXxUlKUQWWLDufqzmJh1HndtR3W9apA2JclPgjfqyneWNM03BF9ZAA)

```js
import { z, ZodObject, ZodArray, ZodRawShape } from "zod";

export function safeKeys<Lookup extends { [k in string]: unknown }>(
  lookup: Lookup
) {
  return Object.keys(lookup) as (keyof Lookup)[];
}

export function mapFrom<Map extends object>(
  keys: readonly (keyof Map)[],
  mapFn: <Key extends keyof Map>(key: Key) => Map[Key]
) {
  return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, mapFn(key)])) as {
    [K in keyof Map]: Map[K];
  };
}

interface Root {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

type RootObjectArray = {
  [F in keyof Root]: Root[F][];
};

const zRoot = z.object({
  userId: z.number(),
  id: z.number(),
  title: z.string(),
  completed: z.boolean(),
});

function toArraySchema<Shape extends ZodRawShape>(schema: ZodObject<Shape>) {
  const shape: Shape = schema.shape;
  return mapFrom<{ [K in keyof Shape]: ZodArray<Shape[K]> }>(
    safeKeys(shape),
    (key) => z.array(shape[key])
  );
}

const zRootObjectArray = z.object(toArraySchema(zRoot));

type ZodRoot = z.infer<typeof zRoot>;
type ZodRootObjectArray = z.infer<typeof zRootObjectArray>

type Equivalent<X, Y> = X extends Y ? (Y extends X ? true : false) : false;

type RootMatches = Equivalent<Root, ZodRoot>;
type RootObjectArrayMatches = Equivalent<RootObjectArray, ZodRootObjectArray>;
```

Comment: It would be great to be able to derive `Map extends object` from the actual `mapFn` rather than it explicitly restating what the mapFn does. I don't think this is possible. In any case the mapFn is constrained to being a function that satisfies the explicit Map declaration, so they are not separate from each other, which eliminates important bugs.

Comment: I invite anyone to copy this and improve on it to deliver a better answer especially around the mapFrom function which is a bit shonky.

Comment: The version at [this typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/N75rGW) makes me a little less ill. It handles the case that From has fewer keys than To, without creating a frankenstein lookup with ghost keys with the `as` clause in mapFrom. Let me know if this is preferred and I'll replace the proven example above.